# bootstrap-select not replicating the same effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using **bootstrap-select** from [here](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

the select i am getting is:
[image]
the original-select i want is(and supposed to get is):
[image]

the difference is in the background(although it is very subtle).
Mine has a button feel, which i dont want. i want it to be plain like the 2nd one.

How do i achieve that?

You can see the **plunkr** demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uuZuURfWFK8l4baNBlNw?p=preview)

Code is given below:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.5/css/bootstrap-select.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
            &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
          <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
      </select>  

        <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-select.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the optional theme

```
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

[see plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EmljessU6dJvpSrw8jvO?p=preview)

Comment: yeah,even i just found it out .... thanks for the effort.... but still when hovering over i am getting unwanted effects..... trying to control it ...

Comment: Ali:will u be able to help me control the hovering over effects

Comment: the hovering hover have the same effect as the original. see it on plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/EmljessU6dJvpSrw8jvO?p=preview

Comment: ok.... i know that. i was asking on how to take control over the hover effect. anyways its fine now. found the solution. Editing the bootstrap-select.js. Thanks for the effort